# Possible Deadpool character cameo

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

I'm trying to figure out who was the person 'Agent Smith' (the Recruiter) was talking to and handed him a business card right before Wade kills 'Agent Smith'?

[image]

Not the actor but rather, was this a **character cameo**?

Comment: What makes you think this a cameo?

Comment: If you can find a Youtube clip, please add it to your post. Anyway, I think IMDB might help you here http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/

Comment: It doesn't appear to be anyone special...just another desperate sick man and there is no credit on IMDB for that. So...who do **you** think it is...and why?

Comment: @mattiav27 those are real life cameos. OP is asking about character cameos, which Deadpool has a ton of.

Comment: HI gang. It sems like it could be a character cameo. It seems to just focus on agent smith handing him a card. I know his hands have some kind of tattoo on them. I was just thinking that this could be a point to add someone in. I will check YouTube for a link if I can find one.

Comment: @Scott I've added the image but it's not anyone special that can be identified. The tattoo on his hand is also not special...it's just the initials USMC.

Comment: Thanks Paulie. Your probably correct. I just figured with the huge mutant universe maybe it was someone.

Comment: "bumped to the homepage by Community" Why?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like it could be a character cameo. It seems to just focus on Agent Smith handing him a card. I know his hands have some kind of tattoo on them.

### It's unlikely.

Certainly it would have been pointed out before by now (but you never know).

There's no indication of any *special* attention being paid to this "character" and *Deadpool* was pretty explicit about all of the "characters" being referenced...except where they weren't allowed to...and even then, they worked around it.

As for the tattoo...it's not a *special* tattoo...just the initials USMC (for US Marine Corps)

[image]

Incidentally, the US Marine Corps would not have permitted that tattoo for serving members...even under their [**new policy**](http://www.marines.mil/News/News-Display/Article/788805/new-marine-corps-tattoo-regulations/).